# Do I have to copy and paste a package?

Tags: python, git, github

I have made a package that controls an Arduino and I want to use it for multiple projects, and still use git. I have tried looking up submodules, and I think they only connect to one commit; as I want it to connect to the latest commit. I did research in Github's package management and this only works for the language I am not working with.

Ex: I have the Arduino package able to control a relay to turn on a lamp. This is activated when the main program for this repo says so. Then I want to create a new project based on Aurdino and use the same package because the code is already there. The problem is that I would have to copy and paste the package manually, or if I wanted to improve my Arduino package I would have to go inside every repo and copy and paste the Arduino package.

Comment: do you know about [branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell#:~:text=A%20branch%20in%20Git%20is,branch%20pointer%20moves%20forward%20automatically.) in git?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of branches but I believe that you can't use another repo to reference a branch.

Comment: branch doesn't create new repo it will create a copy of master? may be use microservices?

Comment: I don't know much about microservices, but I don't think this is the solution. When I just looked it up from a video it says that it is used for service to be connected together. I want two separate repo that both use this one package I made.

Comment: then create a repo with that one package

Comment: This will require me to copy and paste the package to the next repo also

Comment: then why are you using git if you don't want to create new repo or branch etc.

Comment: I still want to use a repo but also have version control on the package so when I update the package it will update all the repo containing the package. You are making it sound like I will have to copy and paste the package.

Comment: Why not put your package onto pip or similar and use it as a dependency?

Comment: That not a bad idea I will look into that thanks